# Cómo puedo abrir un datepicker presionando en el mismo input, y no solo en el icono

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, datepicker

Necesito abrir un datepicker mediante el input, solo abre el calendario al presionar en el icono situado en el lado derecho.

[image]

Como se puede apreciar, solo se abre si presiono en el icono marcado en rojo, pero me gustaría que también se despliegue al presionar en el mismo input en si, en todo el espacio donde muestra la fecha

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fe").datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
</script>
```

```html
<input size="16" type="date" class="form-control" id="fe" name="fe" data-target="#fen" required>
```

Como se puede apreciar, en el mismo HTML está el código y su respectivo JS. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Maestro, su propio ejemplo hace lo que usted pide...

Comment: @MarcePuente no... el OP indica que el calendario sólo se despliega al darle clic al ícono del calendario... y lo que quiere es que se despliegue el calendario al hacer clic en todo el input...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev y es lo que hace, de hecho no hay icono en el ejemplo.

Comment: Es imposible que un input `date` muestre en el campo `03-08-2023`, esto sólo podría ocurrir cuando el campo es de tipo `text`, por lo que el código que adjuntas no creo que sea el que muestras el de tu imagen, por eso es importante adjuntar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: Además, estamos hablando de solo *fecha*, mientras que en tu JS utilizas `datetimepicker`, yo pienso que debería ser `datepicker`. Aquí un [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/RwqvLzG)...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev buena Cris gracias, el último ejemplo ya lo había implementado y funcionó bien. Solo resta ponerlo en español pero se agradece el tiempo, saludos hermano!!!

Comment: Si encontrás una respuesta a tu pregunta, no olvides redactarla como tal. Por cierto, cuando agregás un snippet a tu pregunta, en la sección de JS no debés agregar `<script>` porque esa etiqueta es propia de HTML. No olvides además agregar la versión de jQuery en las opciones listadas (a la izquierda, dentro de la ventana de creación del snippet), para poder reproducir el problema correctamente. Por último: sí hay ícono... O por lo menos se lo puede ver en Firefox :)

Comment: @padaleiana, será que mi Firefox es "veterano"?...

Comment: @MarcePuente imagino que nope.